# Rails - Creating a Landing Page, which is different than the Web App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm rails I've been building a web app.

But the web app is completely different than what the landing page (sign in, register, about, etc should look like)

How do rails developers handle this? Different layouts? Different CSS files? etc..

what's cleanest? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could create a HomePage controller (with associated views), and write the index action for that.

If the layout for the home page is going to be different from the application's again, then in the app/views/layouts/ folder, create a `home_page.html.erb` template. This will automatically be used by a HomePageController instead of the default application.html.erb template.

Comment: Right now my default page is views\pages\home.html.erb ... But that has an IF/ELSE to see if the current_user is signed in. Should I make a home_signin.html.erg and a unsigned_home.html.erb file? If so how?

Comment: Maybe this question can help you with the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993148/rails-displaying-different-view-for-the-same-url . It's a similar question, just not exactly the same as yours.